CORS policy, localhost (chrome fails, postman.co works)
I develop a contact form (beginner). If I use postman.co it works. If I use my front-end it does not work. It fails, because of cors-errors and I do not get it. As far as I know it should work, because I set a header allowing the origin to request resources, but chrome says there was no header. Please have a look at the following code passages and help me out:
Front-End
async function submitHandler() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/Kontakt", {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(formik.values)
        });
        console.log(res.message);
        if (res.message == "message saved") { formik.resetForm(); navigate("/Bestaetigung"); }
        else { navigate("/Fehlgeschlagen"); console.log("fehlgeschlagen1") }
    } catch (error) {
        navigate("/Fehlgeschlagen");
        console.error(error);
    }
};

Back-End
const express = require("express");
const login_routes = require('./router/registered.js').registered;
const general_routes = require('./router/general.js').general;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const PORT = 5000;
app.use("/", general_routes);
app.listen(PORT,()=\>console.log("Server is running"));

general_users.post("/Kontakt", (req, res) =\> {

    var content = req.body;
    content = JSON.stringify(content)
    
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5173");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    fs.appendFile("messages.txt", content, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500).json({error: "message not saved"});
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({message: "message saved"});
        }
    });

});

“Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *” does not work either.
This is what chrome says:

Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/Kontakt' from origin
'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I know that a proxy server could help, but why should I use a proxy if the right code could already be the solution.
I tried different Chrone extensions, but they did not work instantly and I lost the motivation after that. Then there is the possibility to start chrome with a couple of arguments in its shortcut or the like, but if I use "npm run dev" (vite) in vs code it opens always a new window not using the start parameters. I searched a couple of minutes for a free and fast proxy server, but could not find one. Then there are proxy server packages, working with Heroku. This was also new to me and I did not pursue it any longer.
I just would like to know the right code to avoid any supporting tools.

You don't need a proxy or any chrome extensions, you just need a cors middleware on your express server. All the other suggestions you found are for people that try to circomvent these browser restrictions for APIs they don't control, but since you are interacting with your own backend you don't need any of that.

Correct me if I am wrong, but, I should be able to accomplish requests with the means I use, shouldn't I? I thought setting a header should do the trick.
Installed cors package, let's see if it works for me.

Haven't figured out the details, but the cors package allowing simply all kind of requests works. Did not know that I need another tool, thanks.

Evert's comment is sound. Also, there's never a need to include Access-Control-Request-Method in a request, since this is a response header.

Here we can find an examples how to use cors https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html
one of the example which might help you is:
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var allowlist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
var corsOptionsDelegate = function (req, callback) {
  var corsOptions;
  if (allowlist.indexOf(req.header('Origin')) !== -1) {
    corsOptions = { origin: true } // reflect (enable) the requested origin in the CORS response
  } else {
    corsOptions = { origin: false } // disable CORS for this request
  }
  callback(null, corsOptions) // callback expects two parameters: error and options
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptionsDelegate), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for an allowed domain.'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})


before use cors library you need to install it
npm install cors


Ok, yes. For now I use cors() for all origins. Maybe somewhen I will enhance the initial approach and do it right. Currently I am facing another problem. I put the site online and now it does not work any longer. Probably because my backend on my subdomain possesses no ssl certificate.
